# Wordpress Compatibility with a Civi system currently installed on Drupal

Tags: wordpress, drupal

We are currently working with a company using Civi on a Drupal site (CiviCRM 4.4.1) and will be developing a secondary site through wordpress to link into the same Civi Account, we were wondering would there be any compatibility issues? Would these systems all work flawlessly together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is difficult - but not impossible - to do.  CiviCRM has a table (`civicrm_uf_match`) that matches a CiviCRM contact to the corresponding CMS user id - which is pretty difficult to line up if you have multiple CMSes!  There's also settings in `civicrm.settings.php` that define the CMS, which is necessary for, e.g, creating a URL that's correctly formatted for the CMS in question.

You might want to see if just [passing form data from Wordpress to CiviCRM](https://civicrm.org/blogs/erikhommel/passing-form-data-from-wordpress-to-civicrm) meets your needs.  If you're absolutely committed to the path you're suggesting, a good place to start is [here](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=28938.0).